# Getting the elements from Collection MongoDB using Golang and mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, chat, mgo

My task is writing chat with history. So for creating history i need each of messages send to Mongodb and when I have a next connecting I need to getting all messages and, with loop, send to all clients that are connected to chat

This is code of my ChatServer

```
func ChatServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {

// Connecting to MongoDB, collection History
session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://******:*******@ds045795.mongolab.com:45795/catalog")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
c := session.DB("catalog").C("History")

// fmt.Println(c.Find())
// Adding clients to the map
clientId := ws.RemoteAddr().String()
defer ws.Close()
clients[ws] = true

// Loop for receiving msg
for {
    var msg string
    // If can not read msg - delete client from map
    if err := websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg); err != nil {
        delete(clients, ws)
        return
    }
    sendAll(msg)
    err = c.Insert(&Connect{clientId, msg})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
}
```

So **my problem** is getting all the elements in order from the collection.
I have no idea how to do it, because can not find the proper function in documentations.
Maybe you have some other offers?

Comment: You're not inserting a time stamp with the messages?

Comment: No, I am not inserting time stamp

Comment: So how is "order" to be determined? Automagically?

Comment: index in Collection, but i do not know how to detect length of Collection and indexes of docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I agree with commenters above - you should add timestamp to your `Connect` structure. But even without it you can sort your entries by ObjectID as part of it is timestamp. Yes this is quite dirty way and may [cause issues if you use sharding or transfer database to another server](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) but in your case (single Mongolab instance) it's possible with something like like (I don't know your structure so "ip" and "message" are just assumptions)

```
var connects []Connect
c.Find(bson.M{"ip": "127.0.0.1"}).Sort("-_id").Limit(50).All(&connects) // 50 entries in desc order

for _, connect := range connects {
    log.Println(connect.Message)
}
```

But really add time to your `Connect` like that

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Connect struct {
    Ip      string
    Message string
    Ts      time.Time
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://souser:123456@ds055855.mlab.com:55855/catalog")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("catalog").C("History")

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        c.Insert(&Connect{"127.0.0.2", fmt.Sprintf("Test message #%d", i), time.Now()})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    var connects []Connect
    c.Find(bson.M{"ip": "127.0.0.2"}).Sort("-ts").Limit(50).All(&connects)

    for _, connect := range connects {
        log.Println(connect.Message)
    }
}
```

Comment: hello from last question. As I understand it to a certain ip, and I want to display all messages from the collection like this and in order like this: 
[MongoLab Order](http://oi67.tinypic.com/fpa2z9.jpg)
Maybe i do not understand something...

Comment: @ВладДарьев `c.Find(bson.M{}).Sort("_id").All(&connects)`

Comment: and AGAIN VERY BIG THANK TO YOU)), maybe can I ask you sometimes not in stackoverflow?
Can you give me your contacts (mail or something else), of course, if you are not against
Because you helped me second time in two days))